# Traffic shaping under Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, trafficshaping

Where can I learn about controlling/interrogating the network interface under Linux? I'd like to get specific application upload/download speeds, and enforce a speed limit for a specific application.

I'd particularly like information that can help me write a traffic shaping application using Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the iproute2 suite, in which you use the [tc](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/Net:Iproute2_examples) command. tc commands look like

```
tc class add dev eth2 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100Mbit ceil 100Mbit quantum 1600
```

Here's [an existing Python traffic-shaping application](http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/pyshaper/) that uses iproute2.

Answer (score 6):

It is actually quite hard shaping per application using the linux kernel tools, unless the application uses specific ip addresses and/or ports you can match on.

Assuming that is the case then you'll need to read up on `iptables` and in particular fwmarks.  You'll also need to read up on `tc`.  In combination those two tools can do what you want.  The [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control](http://lartc.org/) is a good place to start.

Assuming your application doesn't use a predictable set of ports/ip addresses then you'll need to use a userspace shaper like [Trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle).  This inserts itself between the application and the kernel and shapes the traffic for that application in userspace.

I don't think there are any direct python bindings for any of those tools, but it would be simple to script them using python and just calling the executables directly.

Comment: iptables can match on uid/gid for locally-generated traffic. That makes a convenient way of doing work on specific applications, provided you have some control over the user/group setup of the deployment environment.

Answer (score 1):

Bandwidth limiting for specific application (google-chrome in this case):

```
trickle -d 600 -u 200 google-chrome
```

units are in kbits

Total bandwidth limiting for an ethernet device :

```
sudo wondershaper eth0 600 200
```

Units are in kbits again. Change eth0 to your interface name. It uses tc tbf and htb...

To master connectivity on linux, commands & programs you need to learn are :

```
ip
ifconfig
route
iptables
netstat
tc
wondershaper
trickle
iftop
iptraf-ng
wget 
curl
nslookup
dig
```

The document you need to use as a reference is :

```
https://www.lartc.org/howto/index.html
```

Cookbook has nice examples in this document.

An easy-to-read flowing blog page is :

```
https://www.cnblogs.com/zengkefu/p/5635100.html
```

Do not forget to have fun experimenting with them ;).

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you wish to use python? As mentioned, it will likely only hand-off to already developed tools for this purpose. However, if you look around, you can find things such as `Click! modular router`, `XORP`, and others that provide a drop-in for things you want to do - not to mention all the suggestions already provided (such as `iptables` and `tc`)

Comment: It could  be  for  maintainability. In a python shop  other  users  will get productive more quickly if there is  a  python wrapper.